# I want to display the linear layout in the bottom of the screen.How do I make it align in bottom?

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-linearlayout

This is the xml code for my fragment.I'm able to display the linear layout on top of recyclerview but the problem is, the linear layout doesn't align in bottom of screen.
Should I use relative layout instead of framelayout?

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.dell.pollachiclient.MyCartFragment">

 <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cart"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#Fff"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:background="#Fff"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:textSize="22sp"
        android:text="$500.00"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:background="#FA631D"
        android:text="Checkout"/>
   </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/loPaW.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `RelativeLayout` instead of `FrameLayout` and use

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

in the `LinearLayout` which you want to appear at the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

User RelativeLayout and go with

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#Fff"
    android:layout_below="@id/recycler_view_cart"
     >
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/White">

    <Recycalvire
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/view_a" />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/view_a"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottom_layout"
        android:background="@color/col1"></View>

    <Linearlayout
        layout="@layout/buttom_menu"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as answered by @Nabin Bhandari

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view_cart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#Fff"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroSavebtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#Fff"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="$500.00"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textSize="22sp"
            android:textStyle="normal" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/setup_macroCancelbtn"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FA631D"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="Checkout"
            android:textColor="#fff" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```